# calling a function for fontSize in Doughnut Chart (typescript)

Tags: angular, responsive-design, chart.js

I am trying to call a function in fontSize to take values dynamically

I have written this piece of code, but it's not picking up the value.

```
var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    fontSize: function() {
      if (this.width <= 768) {
        return 10;
      } else {
        return 13;
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `this` inside a callback function which will reset the scope of `this`.

To use the correct scope, change that to an array function. Something like this:

```
var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    fontSize: () => {
      if (this.width <= 768) {
        return 10;
      } else {
        return 13;
      }
    },
  }
}
```

#### UPDATE:

Directly accessing the `window` object isn't really recommended as `window` is a Browser based API and your application **might** run on Angular Universal(in the near future may be) where it might not have access to the Browser based APIs like `window`.

Please consider following this pattern suggested by Brian Love in this article: [Angular Window Provider](https://brianflove.com/2018/01/11/angular-window-provider/)

I know this might sound overwhelming at first but this is the safest way to go about doing it.

Comment: I got it solved by writing it in a different way, thanks though.

Comment: Please do share your implementation as well. Someone might get help in the near future. :)

Comment: sure here it is                                       var width = window.innerWidth;
   if (width <= 768) {
     myDoughnutChart.options.legend.labels.fontSize = 10;
     myDoughnutChart.update();
   } else {
     myDoughnutChart.options.legend.labels.fontSize = 13;
     myDoughnutChart.update();
   }
  }